# Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi Error running example

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi3

I installed tensorflow v1.1.0 from "https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi ".
Now I'm trying to run a code from the examples given on the tensorflow website.
This is the error I keep getting:

> "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'feature_column'".

I am using `Debian Jessie` with `python 2.7.9`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please add your code and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

> "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'feature_column'".
>
> What could be the problem?

`tf.feature_column` was introduced in Tensorflow `v 1.2.0` on `June 16, 2017`.

You have Tensorflow  version `v1.1.0`. Any example which requires `feature_column` will not run.